# I have a problem with videojs node-modules

Tags: javascript, node-modules, video.js

so i export my project from codesandbox (it works there) to visual code and now im having problems with this ...´

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @charset "UTF-8";
| .vjs-modal-dialog .vjs-modal-dialog-content, .video-js .vjs-modal-dialog, .vjs-button > .vjs-icon-placeholder:before, .video-js .vjs-big-play-button .vjs-icon-placeholder:before {
|   position: absolute;
 @ ./src/Components/Work/videojs.js 3:0-36
 @ ./src/Components/Work/Video.js
 @ ./src/Components/Work/index.js
´´´

I already install from npm all the dependencies that i have in codesandbox.
glad if anyone can answer this
```

Comment: Could You provide working example that reproduces your problem (eg. git repo) ???

Comment: is there a code sandbox link?

Comment: Check your nodejs version

Comment: @VincenzoNinni i have v12.13.0

Comment: @Nelles https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-https-7zccz

Comment: @SkorpEN after some new things i try i have this  `ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Miguel\Documents\Bitbucket\educast_editor\.babelrc: Error while parsing config - JSON5: invalid character '{' at 7:7`

Comment: @Miguel Rodrigues It looks like videojs problem is solved. You might got other problem, but version on codesandbox work at start. So maybe search for other problems and if not found then ask new question. This one probably shoud be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The path is wrong:

```
import "video.js/dist/video-js.css";
```

You need to give the full path:

```
import "/node-modules/video.js/dist/video-js.css";
```

Comment: now i have this error           ´
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: .presets[0][1] must be an object, false, or undefined `    and my .babelrc is                                       `{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/transform-runtime",
    [
      "import",
      {
        "libraryName": "@material-ui/icons",
        "libraryDirectory": "",
        "camel2DashComponentName": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
`